# $( "#id" ).val(); showing incorrect result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender" required><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender" required><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
  </label>
</div>
```

If I select the Male option and run `val()` I don't get Male:

```
$( "#gender" ).val();
"Female"
```

Why do I get Female?

Comment: Id gender should be unique

Comment: You can't have two the same ids in your html

Comment: It can't be unique, it's a gender selector. I want to get the value of whatever one is selected. Only one can be selected.

Comment: name must be common for data posting but ID must be unique , try something like gender_male and gender_female

Answer (score 3):

Because both radio buttons have the same ID (which btw is invalid in HTML). Use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) alongside the [checked pseudo selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) instead:

```js
alert($("input[name='gender']:checked").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required checked><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Achecked) for this.

```js
$('input[name="gender"]').change(function(){
    alert($('input[name="gender"]:checked').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender_female" required><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender_male" required><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html be

```
<div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"  required><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
  </label>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("input[name=gender]").click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gtsjhe1y/3/)